# How could the exception specifier on move assignment operator affect that of move constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, c++14, noexcept

I've being testing with GCC 5.2 and clang 3.6, both in C++14 mode, and they give the same output.

For the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
  // S& operator= (S&&) noexcept { return *this; }
};


int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<S>::value
            << std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<S>::value;  
}
```

the result `11` is obtained. But if uncomment the move assignment operator, the output becomes `01`. How could an explicit `noexcept` specification on the move assignment operator possibly affect that of the move constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By defining the move assignment operator, you disabled the move constructor due to the [rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11). The class isn't `is_nothrow_move_constructible` because it isn't move constructable at all, that constructor is no longer available unless you define it.

**§12.8 Copying and moving class objects**

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   — **`X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,**
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>   — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

In the case where you had no user-defined move constructor, both were implicitly defined and followed the below specification.

**§15.4 Exception specifications**

> An implicitly declared special member function shall have an exception-specification. If `f` is an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit exception-specification specifies the type-id `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the exception-specification of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` shall allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and **`f` shall allow no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions**.

Answer (score 5):

By declaring a move assignment, you've lost your implicit move constructor.
See the full chart below.

[image]

Comment: Nice chart! BTW, why are those defaulted fields dark red?

Comment: Because it's extremely dangerous.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @LogicStuff  The red squares indicate deprecated behavior starting after C++98/03. In newer standards, I believe they become "not declared", but I'm not too sure there is a guarantee on that.  They appear not declared, in my version of clang.

Comment: I guess I will just remember the first three rows.

Comment: Here is a thread involving Howard Hinnant, than man who made this table:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342941/what-are-the-rules-for-automatic-generation-of-move-operations

Howard's presentation:  
http://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf

Comment: Nice chart!  Thanks for the link.  Red means deprecated in C++11 and forward.  They have not been removed, but they might be in a future standard.  Guideline:  Don't depend on deprecated behavior.  If you explicitly declare any one of the destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment, then explicitly declare both the copy constructor and copy assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The move constructor is simply not generated in this case - it has nothing to do with `noexcept`.

From cppreference:

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators
> - **there are no user-declared move assignment operators**
> - there are no user-declared destructors
>     (until C++14)
>
> the implicitly-declared move constructor is not defined as deleted due to conditions detailed in the next section
>   then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&).

Answer (score 2):

12.8/9:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

By declaring a move assignment operator, you prevent the class from having any move constructor at all.

Answer (score 1):

By defining the move operator, you've suppressed the implicit move constructor. That's why `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` fails. Provide it to get the desired output:

```
struct S {
  S(S&&) noexcept {}
  S& operator= (S&&) noexcept { return *this; }
};
```