# Does base class destructor prevent move constructor being generated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a class where VS 2015 was not generating a move ctor and now VS 2015 Update 1 it is generating one, this is causing a binary compatibility issue, not sure which version is doing the right thing.

```
// MyLib
struct Shared
{
   virtual ~Shared(){}
}

struct Callback : public Shared
{
    virtual void response() = 0;
}

// App
struct CallbackI : public Callback
{
   virtual void response(){}
}
```

When I build MyLib with VS 2015 and App with VS 2015 update 1 linking App fails because a missing symbol referencing the move assignment operator for Callback base class.

Seems to me that VS 2015 is not generating this operators and VS 2015 Update 1 it is, but which compiler version is right here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33057705/1348273.

Answer (score 3):

VS 2015 Update 1 is doing the right thing (and actually the first VS version that implements all of C++11)

From the standard:

> **§12.8 Copying and moving class objects**
>
> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only
>   if
>
> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

The user-generated destructor in `Shared` implicitly marks the move constructor as deleted. When you let the compiler generate it, the compiler can also generate the move assignment operator.

```
struct Shared
{
   virtual ~Shared() = default;
}
```

For performance reasons, it's also better to declare empty virtual destructors this way because it guarantees inlining by the compiler.

Comment: My understanding is that Shared having a user defined destructor prevents the move assignment and move constructors from being generated, and so the derived types will not have one.

Comment: in other words "T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be move-assigned (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move assignment operator);" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment

Comment: IMO vs 2015 Update 1 is wrong as the user defined destructor in Shared should prevent the move assignment operator being generated, and that should affect Callback derived class as it has a virtual base class that has a deleted move assignment operator.