# How to forbid assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a reason to use the “canonical” signatures for `operator=`

```
class X {
  X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
  X& operator=(X&&) = delete;
};
```

instead of just

```
class X {
  void operator=(X) = delete;
};
```

when all you want to do is `delete` it?

**Upd:**
Also, consider a situation when `X` has an explicitly declared move or copy constructor.

```
class X {
public:
  X(X&&);
};
```

In that case `op=(X&&)` and `op=(const X&)` are implicitly deleted, but I want to explicitly express that assignment is not allowed.

Comment: Does your version even work? The compiler doesn't define that version on its own, so deleting it shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @MarkRansom you can delete whatever you want. It's not `=default`

Comment: Why do you need to delete both the copy and move assignment operators in the first example? `X& operator=(const X&) = delete;` alone should be enough, no? A move assignment operator will not be implicitly declared due to the presence of your user declared copy assignment operator.

Comment: @MarkRansom Seems to work in a simple example: http://ideone.com/DAuDFH.

Comment: @Praetorian, I don't really need it. I just I want to explicitly say that `X` is not assignable in any way.

Comment: @Ben so the same statement both declares and deletes the function? Fascinating. P.S. using `struct` instead of `class` for a quick example will prevent the errors regarding private members.

Comment: If you want to be explicit about it, use the first version. Otherwise the second version `void operator=(X) = delete;` should also achieve the same effect, as far as I can tell.

Comment: As a guideline, never delete the special move members.  If you do so, the best you can hope for is that you've created redundant noise.  At worst, it won't do what you were hoping for.  `X& operator=(const X&) = delete;` is sufficient, and succinct.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: `X& operator=(X) = delete;` seems to be even more succinct and should also be sufficient.

Comment: @DietmarKühl:  Yes, identical in functionality.  Not more succinct though (both one liners).  And questionable on readability because the `X& operator=(const X&) = delete;` is more common/familiar and so your reader has to stop and figure out why the unusual signature.  Ultimately this boils down to a style issue, and I'm recommending `X& operator=(const X&) = delete;`.

Comment: Tape this above your monitor until you have it memorized: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/576911 :-)

Comment: And unit test all 6 special member whether you have them or not like this:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/test/date_test/day.pass.cpp#L62-L67

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, there is no technical reason to use the canonical copy assignment operator signature.**

As seen in the standard, [dcl.fct.def.delete] §8.4.3:

> 2. A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.
>      [ Note: This includes calling the function implicitly or explicitly and forming a pointer or pointer-to-member
>      to the function. It applies even for references in expressions that are not potentially-evaluated. **If a function
>      is overloaded, it is referenced only if the function is selected by overload resolution.** — end note ]

Therefore a deleted function's name, in this case `operator=`, may only be used if the compiler finds a preferable overload resolution. However, such an overload cannot exist, as `X` and `const X&` are indistinguishable as parameters ([over.ics.rank] §13.3.3.2) and the return value is ignored.

**That being said**, there *is* a stylistic reason to use the canonical signature. The mere fact that this question exists shows that anyone reading your code may *not* know the meaning and assume it is doing something special. For readability's sake, I would recommend you use the familiar `X& operator=(const X&) = delete;`.