# Why the below code does not compile with gcc but compiles fine with clang

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-constructor, noexcept

Below code compiles fine with clang but not gcc , any explanation is this a bug in gcc?

Its just a class which contains a vector of unique_ptr and std::function as member and when I create vector of this class , I cant say reserve or resize on this. push_back works fine with std::move, while this only happens with gcc and not clang.

```
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                               
#include <memory>                                                                                                                                                          
#include <utility>                                                                                                                                                         
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                       

class ABC                                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                                                                                    
    ABC()                                                                                                                                                                  
          {}                                                                                                                                                               
  private:                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> up;                                                                                                                                  
    std::function<void (int*)> func;                                                                                                                                       
};                                                                                                                                                                         

int main()                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    ABC a;                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::vector<ABC> vec;                                                                                                                                                  
    vec.reserve(1);                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Error message looks like below for gcc

```
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
                 from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
                 from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/algorithm:62,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}]':
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<int>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]'
prog.cc:10:7:   required from 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = ABC; _Args = {const ABC&}]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const ABC*; _ForwardIterator = ABC*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const ABC*; _ForwardIterator = ABC*]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = const ABC*; _ForwardIterator = ABC*; _Tp = ABC]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1263:35:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = const ABC*; _Tp = ABC; _Alloc = std::allocator<ABC>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = ABC*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/vector.tcc:73:40:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = ABC; _Alloc = std::allocator<ABC>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
prog.cc:24:18:   required from here
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/memory:80:0,
                 from prog.cc:2:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please post the error message from the compiler.

Comment: In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/memory:80:0,
                 from prog.cc:2:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Add the error message to your post, with appropriate formatting.

Comment: I dont think its hard to reach out to some compiler to try it out yourself, as error message is very ugly.  try wandbox

Comment: added the error message to the post, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `std::function`'s move ctor is not `noexcept`, but a `std::vector` can only use the move ctor if it's `noexcept` (strong exception guarantee).

The issue is that `std::unique_ptr` is (obviously) non-copyable, so that makes `ABC` noncopyable as a whole.
To make `ABC` `noexcept`-movable implicitly, it'd need every one of its members to be `noexcept`-movable as well.

If you remove the `std::function`, that's what happens: the `.resize()` doesn't need to copy `A.up` (a `std::vector`'s move operator is `noexcept`), so the `std::unique_ptr`s (inside `up`) can just be moved, and everything works fine.

See [**this coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d118f39f9e1f993e): if you comment the `noexcept`, `vec.reserve()` will need to copy everything, and the issue comes back.

Adding `ABC(ABC&&) = default` fixes the issue because user-declared (though `default`ed) move ctor inhibits the generation of copy constructor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/1737909)).

We can also go the opposite way and manually delete `A`'s copy constructor in the coliru (and keep the move ctor *not* `noexcept`): [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3282bd86ddd5515e).

---

To fix the issue, you *could* store the `std::function` in a `std::unique_ptr`, which has a `nothrow` move ctor. [**See here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d23867a8a69b24)

Comment: It does help: [here with `noexcept` move ctor but deleted copy ctor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3282bd86ddd5515e)

Comment: My point was that its the manual declaration of `noexcept` move-ctor that's key. You don't have to touch the copy-ctor at all, and if you *only* try to delete it, it won't work.

Comment: No, that's just because declaring a copy ctor prevents the declaration of a move ctor. This is why the coliru I linked to has the move ctor declared.

Comment: The root cause is that `vector<unique_ptr>>` pretends that it is copyable when it isn't. That, in turn, causes `ABC` to pretend to be copyable when it isn't. Then, `vector<ABC>` goes "Are you nothrow movable? No? Are you copyable? Yes? Then I'll copy you so that we have strong exception safety." And bam, explosions.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* that GCC is being picky about constructors; it blocks the generation of the move-ctor<sup>1</sup>. It stops complaining after you provide them explicitely:

```
class ABC                                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                                                                                    
    ABC() = default;        // <-- 
    ABC(ABC&&) = default;   // <--
  private:                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> up;                                                                                                                                  
    std::function<void (int*)> func;                                                                                                                                       
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* (again, I'm not sure), that his happens because the default copy-ctor of `ABC` is defined as `noexcept` and is as such preferred over the default move-ctor (it's still ill-formed because we're dealing with non-copyable members here). Trying to generate a defaulted `noexcept` move-ctor result in:

```
main.cpp:14:4: note: 'ABC::ABC(ABC&&) noexcept' is implicitly deleted because its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ''
    ABC(ABC&&) noexcept = default;
    ^~~
```

As such, forcing the generation of no-`noexcept` move-ctor allows it to be picked. Why Clang doesn't have a problem with that - I don't know.

One explanation for the above is hinted by the fact that removing `std::function` allows the defaulted `noexcept` move-ctor to be generated. `std::function` doesn't have a `noexcept` move-ctor (which [sucks tremendously](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37526154#37526154)), so the whole class falls back to the copy-ctor. Since `unique_ptr` doesn't have one, the whole thing breaks.

Comment: Let me know if I should go digging for a standard quote.

Comment: Also having just one of `vector` or `function` makes the defaulted move-ctor be generated properly. Strange...

Comment: Indeed , just the combination of this two is causing the issue, while either of them compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

GCC accepted the lack of noexcept on std::function's move ctor as bug

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81017

//  -*- C++ -*-

```
  /** 2227        *  @brief %Function move constructor. 2228        *  @param
 __x A %function object rvalue with identical call signature. 2229        * 2230        
*  The newly-created %function contains the target of @a __x 2231        *  (if 
it has one). 2232        */ 2233       
function(function&& __x) : _Function_base()  {     __x.swap(*this); }
```