# Explicit move constructor needed in container?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a templated container class:

```
 template<class Stuff>
 class Bag{
     private:
        std::vector<Stuff> mData;
 };
```

I want to do

```
  void InPlace(Bag<Array>& Left){
      Bag<Array> temp;
      Transform(Left, temp); //fills temp with desirable output
      Left = std::move(temp);
  }
```

Suppose Array has user-defined move semantics, but Bag does not. Would mData in this case be moved or copied?

Comment: good catch, fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be moved, not copied.

I would suggest looking at the following image:

---

[image]

---

This clearly shows that the compiler implicitly generates a move constructor as long as the user doesn't define his/her own :

- destructor
- copy constructor
- copy assignment
- move assignment

Since your class has none of these user defined constructors the compiler generated move constructor will be called, that constructor will move `mData`.

Comment: Where is this nice table from?

Comment: @zett42 I forgot, I just have it laying around. However, I did a quick search and it's from a presentation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/1870760

Comment: The actual presentation : https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf

Comment: This very usefully answers the question I asked, but I was actually interested in the case when Bag does *not* have an implicitly generated move constructor. Should I ask a new one?