# Explicit move constructor needed in container with no compiler-defined move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

This is a modification of my earlier question [Explicit move constructor needed in container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573222/explicit-move-constructor-needed-in-container).

I have a templated container class:

```
template<class Stuff>
class Bag{
     public: 
        ~Bag() {//Do some stuff here so that the compiler doesn't implement move semantics}
     private:
        std::vector<Stuff> mData;
 };
```

I want to do

```
void InPlace(Bag<Array>& Left){
  Bag<Array> temp;
  Transform(Left, temp); //fills temp with desirable output
  Left = std::move(temp);
}
```

Suppose Array has user-defined move semantics, but Bag does not. Would mData in this case be moved or copied?

Comment: Are you planning to ask a question about every row in that grid?

Comment: If `Bag` is not movable why would a move happen?

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44573222/7359094) you asked 2 hours ago.

Comment: Bag does not have a move constructor, so temp gets cast to an lvalue (by the assignment operator). If I had to guess I would think this means that the std::vector assignment (not move) operator gets called, since mData is also an lvalue, but I'm not totally sure, hence the question. Sorry?

Comment: If an object is not movable then move falls back to copy.  That means `Left = std::move(temp);` is copy assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Bag supports no move semantics then there is no move operations applicable. Copy assignment/construction will take place accordingly.

Comment: Btw. temp is an lvalue so it wouldn't result in a move here anyway.