# Has it been established if move/copy constructor/assignment are "deleted" or "not declared" in C++17?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/1366368) regarding [What are the rules for automatic generation of move operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342941/what-are-the-rules-for-automatic-generation-of-move-operations), and am hopeful that the answer has now been well established by now.

The slide that shows what constructors/assignment operators are "not declared", "defaulted" or "deleted", based on what has been declared in the class, shows:

[image]

That was taken from these [slides](https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf), with the red squares meaning that this behaviour is deprecated.

When compiling the following:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X
{
  template<typename...T>
  X(T&&...) {
    std::cout << "Yay!\n";
  }

  ~X() {}
};

int main() {
  X x0;
  X x1{x0};
  X x2{std::move(x0)};
}
```

It would appear that they have been "not declared", since it compiles and the output is "Yay!" three times (which is good, at least for me).  But I want to confirm that I can rely on this behaviour.

## Edit

It has been pointed out by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442671/frank) that, if a copy constructor is also added, it still says "Yay!" three times, which is interesting behaviour.  Doing further testing, if a move constructor is added, it will only say "Yay!" twice.  Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: "It would appear that they have been "not declared"", not necessarily, that user-defined constructor binds VERY agressively: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BKxKTLY4RUAfhTnC

Comment: @Frank, I'm not sure what you mean.  If constructor is not defined, then the template will match, otherwise, it will not.

Comment: @Adrian I meant that your assumption that seeing "Yay!" three times implies that the constructors do not exist is not correct. It just means that they are not used, present or not. In my example, I explicitely add the copy constructor back in, yet it still prints out "Yay!" three times.

Comment: Your template generates normal, not copy- or move-constructors. A copy/move constructor can never be a template. A catch-all templated constructor is also very, very dangerous, it will match literally anything, and will almost always be a better match.

Comment: Oh, I missed that @Frank.  That's indeed interesting.

Comment: @rustyx, yes, but if the copy/move constructors are not defined, then the templated constructor is free to bind in place of the copy/move constructors. As I understand it, if a move/copy constructor was defined/deleted, it should bind to those over any templated function.

Comment: If that's the case @n.m., then what are the rules for when a templated constructor with a universal reference could override a copy/move constructor that exists?

Comment: I have missed the dtor. Sorry about the confusion. Only copy ctor/assignment are defaulted.

Comment: Np @n.m..  That's why I added whitespace, to bring attention to the dtor.  Need to understand the binding to the template with universal reference over the copy ctor though.

Comment: Your template ctor is a better match than the copy ctor (a non-const reference is a better match than a const reference).

Comment: Oh, of course. @Frank, do you understand?  If I change the line 16 in your example from `X x1{x0};` to `X x1{static_cast<X const&>(x0)};`, it will explicitly call the copy constructor, regardless if you specify the copy ctor or not, since it is already defined as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to N4659 (almost C++17 standard), they are still defined as defaulted but the behavior is (still) deprecated.

- For the copy constructor, see [[class.copy.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#6):

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, *it is defined as defaulted. The latter case is **deprecated** if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor.*

- For the copy assignment, see [[class.copy.assign]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign#2):

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, *it is defined as defaulted. The latter case is **deprecated** if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor.*

Comment: Not sure how [\[class.copy.ctor\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#1) relates to my example.

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, I did not catch what was your intent.

Comment: @Adrian You can use GCC9 with command line `-Wdeprecated-copy` and `-Wdeprecated-copy-dtor` or just `-Wextra` to get warnings ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pyABve))

Comment: The intent was to get a templated ctor to with a universal reference to bind in place of a copy/move ctor.