# Is there any reason to mark a constructor of an abstract class as explicit

Tags: c++, abstract-class, explicit-constructor

In the following example, my class is abstract due to the abstract method `run`. I also have a constructor from another type. I always mark constructor having only 1 argument as `explicit`, except when I WANT implicit cast available. But, in the special case of an abstract class, is there any reason to justify it ?

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void run() = 0; // Then the class is abstract
    explicit Foo(Bar const& bar);
};
```

Note: my question is purely technical: **is there any way to have a different behaviour with or without the explicit keyword on a constructor of an abstract class ?**

Comment: If you always do it, then just do it for consistency. It doesn't hurt, even if it might have little effect.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen actually my question is technical : is there any way to have a different behaviour with or without the `explicit` keyword on a constructor of an abstract class ?

Comment: @Bop this "doesn't hurt" is not 100% true. Only when you remember about move constructor and assignment. Blindly adding this will silently disable move c-tor and move assignment and this can be harmful for performance. [See table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56100502/1387438).

Comment: @MarekR That's not a copy constructor.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've missed that :(. But on other had this make this question even more strange. I wonder if this is a typo.

Comment: An abstract class shouldn’t have public constructors in the first place. See <https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-copy-virtual>.

Comment: @user3840170 - That guideline is about copy/move. The OP's c'tor is neither.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed due to similarity to another question that is not related to abstract classes. My question is explicitly about abstract classes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But, in the special case of an abstract class, is there any reason to justify it ?

If you use copy-list-initialization and inheriting constructors, it [prevents some implicit conversions](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:21),source:%27class+Bar%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Foo%0A%7B%0A++public:%0A++++virtual+void+run()+%3D+0%3B+//+Then+the+class+is+abstract%0A++++explicit+Foo(Bar+const%26)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Fuzz+:+public+Foo+%7B%0A++++using+Foo::Foo%3B%0A++++void+run()+override+%7B%7D+%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo(Foo+*f)+%7B+f-%3Erun()%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Bar+b%3B%0A++++Fuzz+f+%3D+%7Bb%7D%3B%0A++++foo(%26f)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g132,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1600,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+2/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

```
class Fuzz : public Foo {
    using Foo::Foo;
    void run() override {} 
};

Bar b;
Fuzz f = {b}; // Error when Foo's c'tor is explicit
```

Now this is pretty specific, but if your goal is to prevent implicit conversions, and given how complicated C++'s initialization rules are, better be consistent and `explicit`.