# How to find out which functions the compiler generated?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know about compiler-generated functions, the rule of three and the rule of five. In real-world scenarios, it may not be trivial to figure out exactly which of the compiler-generated functions (constructors, assignment operators, destructor) were actually created by the compiler.

**Is there any way to list the compiler-generated functions for a specific class?**

I am primarily interested in Visual Studio 2019 and Xcode, but a generic solution would be even more welcome.

Answer (score 17):

The rules are complicated. I will steal [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/2805305) which quotes a table from [Howard Hinnant's presentation](http://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf).

[image]

The moral here is that a good practice is to **not rely** on compiler implicit declares and explicitly declare every special member (as defaulted or deleted, depending on your needs)

Comment: If you explicitly declare every special member you lose "not declared" special members status for move constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin my point is to declare them defaulted if you need them (although default can still mean not declared) or deleted if you don't want them.

Comment: Once you declare them they are no longer "not declared".

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin you are right, I meant deleted. For instance if you have a `unique_ptr` member and you declare the copy assign `default` it will be deleted because of that member. That's what I meant.

Comment: @bolov The chart is useful but this does not answer my question. I want to find out which functions were actually generated by the compiler. In other words: I am not asking about what should happen in theory, but what is happening in practice.

Comment: And that deleted member triggers a compiler error where "non declared" member wouldn't. That forces you to actually implement manually that member instead of writing "= default". "Non declared" is different from default and deleted, you may like to re-watch the talk you are quoting the picture from.

Comment: @HelgeKlein, if "in practice" the compiler generates anything other than what should be generated "in theory" then the compiler is incorrect and there is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: By that argument, we would never need to test our code, because we'd know that if the compiler did anything different than we intended then there must be a bug in it.

Comment: @ruakh if you don't trust your compiler to do what it is supposed to do how can you trust the testing tools to do what they are supposed to do?

Comment: @bolov: I do trust my compiler to do what it's supposed to do, but I don't trust *myself* to 100% reliably identify what my compiler's supposed to do in a given case, especially since a small typo can have massive semantic implications. (Though I guess that's why I don't usually use C++. C++ programmers do have to trust themselves to be perfect, despite all evidence to the contrary, because you can't test for UB . . .)

Comment: @ruakh, Compilers are generally very heavily tested, you should be able to trust that your compiler will generate exactly what is documented in the C++ standard and nothing more/nothing less. If you can't trust your compiler to do that, then you should find a new compiler. What you can't trust is whether the input you give the compiler is correct, and that's why having tests for your own code is so important.

Comment: In other words, you don't need tests to verify that the compiler is correct. You need tests to verify that you provided the compiler with the correct input. So testing is still very much required.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Yes, exactly. Likewise, the point of seeing what your compiler has generated is not to verify that the compiler is correct, but rather, to verify that you provided the compiler with the correct input.

Answer (score 7):

> "Is there any way to list the compiler-generated functions for a specific class?"

Of course there is. On **Linux** (and other Unix systems) you can use `nm`, `readelf` and `objdump` on the generated object files/libraries/executable to disassemble them and inspect any exported symbols (and much more).

There are similar tools on **Windows**, I know, but that's not a platform I work much with, so unfortunately I cannot name exact tool names there.

Comment: Although these tools may very well not show you what functions _might_ have been generated (i.e., the compiler was allowed to generate them, but you never used those functions so it decided to not bother, or link-time code elimination got rid of them)

Comment: @JMAA In most cases, "allowed to generate but never used" would in Standard terms mean that a function was "implicitly declared" but was not "implicitly defined". Yes, this still means you won't see the symbols, even if inlining is disabled.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this answer does more precisely responds to the question asked: "Which methods did the compiler generate?" That is not the same as the much less precise question "Which methods might have been generated by the compiler in a different context?"

Comment: @rici True. But the more precise question is not easily answerable, so I went for what could be answered. Feel free to downvote if you think my answer is not valuable.

Comment: @jesper: no, i already upvoted. I think the question you answered is more precise, as I said. The other question, which might have been the intent, requires some handwaving because it's contrafactual: we don't know what hypothetical contexts it might include.  But this is the question literally asked, intentionally or not, so kudos for answering it.

Comment: @ric: The question is asking about the *compiler*. This answer is only based on what the *linker* left. So no, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @IInspectable: ELF is the format of the *compiler*'s output (on Linux). So if you invoke `gcc -c` you get an ELF-format file, which you can pass through the various utilities mentioned in this answer. The linker doesn't come into it.

Comment: @ric: This is straight from this answer: *"you can use nm, readelf and objdump on the generated object files/libraries/executable"*.

Comment: @IInspectable: That's right. The generated **object file** is what the compiler produces. Object files are the input to the linker, which produces an executable. So you can *also* use those utilities on linker output, but you can specifically use them on compiler output. (Or on the output of an *archiver* which combines several object files into a library.)

Comment: @ric: Did you not read *"executable"* in the answer? Run them tools on the executable, and you do not get the answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Iinspectable: Yes, but it provides a list of possible things you can run those tools on. That is, I'm reading "object files/libraries/executable" as "object files *or* libraries *or* executable", because that's the only reading which makes sense. Those three terms are not aliases or synonyms for each other.

Comment: @ric: Sure, but why mention *"executables"* when the question **explicitly** asks about the compiler?

Comment: @IInspectable: it doesn't invalidate an answer to also provide extra related information beyond what was requested. On the contrary, it makes the question and answer more useful for future readers with similar but not identical questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently only a partial answer.

### Visual Studio 2019

#### Constructors

When defining a class object, Visual Studio's IntelliSense function shows the available constructors, both compiler-generated and your own:

[image]

This information does not always come up, unfortunately. To get it to work for the screenshot above, I had to type something in the parentheses, hence the comma.