# C++ primer 5 ed. Virtual destructor and move semantics

Tags: c++, inheritance, move-semantics, virtual-destructor

In C++ primer 5 ed. it is said:

> "The fact that a base class needs a virtual destructor has an important indirect impact on the definition of base and derived classes: If a class defines a destructor—even if it uses = default to use the synthesized version—the compiler will not synthesize a move operator for that class (§13.6.2, p. 537)."

So for more understanding I've tried this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){cout << "A::A()\n";}
    virtual ~A(){cout << "A::~A()\n";}
    A& operator = (const A&) {cout << "A::=\n"; return *this;};
    A& operator = (A&&) = default;
};

int main()
{

    A a;
    A a2;
    a2 = std::move(a); // why copy-assignment operator is not called here. Normally a will be "moved" through copy-ctor (moving through working copy-ctor)


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- So according to the text above in the book `class A` has a `virtual` destructor thus the compiler won't synthesize a move-ctor/assignment operations But in `main` I've tried to move an object of type `class A` so normally `move` here uses copy-assignment instead of move-assignment but copy-assignment is not called here?!
- So when a vairtual dtor causes a default operation be not synthesized? Thank you!

Comment: *even if it uses = default to use the synthesized version* - This applies to the destructor. I.e. if one defines `virtual ~A() = default;`

Comment: The quote says the compiler won't **implicitly** declare a move assignment operator. But you explicitly asked for one to be defined. In any case, a move assignment is not implicitly declared when a user-defined copy assignment is provided; this is independent of whether the destructor is virtual.

Comment: Is it time for the [chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59616399/576911)? :-)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Still have the same confusion. Could you explain please.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That means the normal rule applies: if a class defines a destructor (virtual or non-virtual) then the compiler won't synthesize a move operation for that class. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. What the book is trying to say, I think, is that, if you need a virtual destructor, then you must define one - you can't simply omit it. And that has a side effect of suppressing move operations, so now those need to be defined, too (assuming the class needs them, of course).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Perfect! Thank you! I think you should post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook is right, the compiler won't automatically synthesize a move operator. In the code sample you force the compiler to generate one by setting it to default, this can only fail if the move operator is implicitly *deleted*. Which is something else than it being implicitly *declared*.

Criteria for implicit *deletion*:

> - A has a non-static data member that is const
> - A has a non-static data member of a reference type
> - A has a non-static data member that cannot be move-assigned (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move assignment operator)
> - A has direct or virtual base class that cannot be move-assigned (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move assignment operator)
> - A has a non-static data member or a direct or virtual base without a move assignment operator that is not trivially copyable
> - A has a direct or indirect virtual base class

Criteria for implicit *declaration*:

> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared move constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared destructors;
> - the implicitly-declared move assignment operator would not be defined as deleted

[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)